# How to show video from RSS link on site

Tags: php, xml

Using the following link I got RSS feed for videos
http://rss.cnn.com/services/podcasting/ac360/rss.xml

I need to fetch this link and show video on my site using DOMDocument() in PHP.
How to fetch these videos from RSS feed and show on my site ?
Here is my code

```
$xml=("rss.cnn.com/services/podcasting/ac360/rss.xml";);
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml); 
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0); 
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {      
    $item_title=$x->item($i)
                  ->getElementsByTagName('title')
                  ->item(0)
                  ->childNodes
                  ->it‌​em(0)
                  ->nodeValue;   
    $item_link=$x->item($i)
                 ->getElementsByTagName('link')
                 ->item(0)
                 ->childNodes
                 ->item‌​(0)
                 ->nodeValue;  
    $item_desc=$x->item($i)
                 ->getElementsByTagName('description')
                 ->item(0)
                 ->childNode‌​s
                 ->item(0)
                 ->nodeValue;
    echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link. "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
}
```

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: $xml=("http://rss.cnn.com/services/podcasting/ac360/rss.xml");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);


for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
{

  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

   echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link. "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
 
  }

Answer (score 1):

The video url's are under the `<media:content>` tag's `url` attribute, you could use xpath to grab those like this:

```
$xml=("rss.xml");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//item') as $item) {
    $media = $xpath->query('//media:content', $item);
    $title = $xpath->query('//title', $item);
    print '<a href="'.$media->item(0)->getAttribute('url').'">'.$title->item(0)->textContent."</a>\n";
}
```

also consider using rss parsing libraries like [simplepie](http://www.simplepie.org/)